# Caught exception during boot ConfigurationPersistenceException

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, wildfly

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Netbeans 8.0.2
- Wildfly 8.2.1
- JDK 1.8.0_60

I can build without error, but when I try to Run the project I get this error, but I don't have any persistance configuration yet.

**Error log**

```
11:47:56,871 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
11:47:57,070 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
11:47:57,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
11:47:57,534 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:112)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:3.0}server'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104)
    ... 3 more

11:47:57,535 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
11:47:57,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015950: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" stopped in 3ms
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server can't start because there is an issue with your server configuration. According to your error message, your configuration starts with something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">
...
```

but wildfly 8.2.1 as I know supports server configuration version 2.2 and your config should look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">
...
```

How could this happen? Most probably, you have misconfigured your IDE or environment properties, so that Wildfly looks in wrong place for configuration. Check JBOSS_HOME environment property, in most situations you don't need that, so unset it.

```
$ env | grep JBOSS_HOME
```

otherwise review carefully your server configuration in Netbeans.

Comment: You need to check the configuration file path you gave to the IDE as it uses it to start the server. If there was a prior configuration the path to the configuration file is NOT updated when you change the installation directory.

Comment: The problem was that I use 2 different wildfly servers with netbeans, wildfly 9 that uses <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">, and wildfly 8 thas uses <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">, but when I added the server 8 to netbeans, it used by default the xml configuration from wildfly 9