# Cannot start JBoss server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

```
12:03:29,479 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.Final-redhat-1
12:03:29,949 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
12:03:30,072 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) starting
12:03:30,678 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:308) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:188) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:2.2}server'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 3 more

12:03:30,682 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
12:03:30,711 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) stopped in 13ms
```

I'm using JBoss 6.1+ server in eclipse Luna and I'm trying to start it, but I end up getting the above error. Not sure why? Any help ? I'm using 1.7 JDK,
I searched [Caught exception during boot ConfigurationPersistenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284795/caught-exception-during-boot-configurationpersistenceexceptionMany), the configuration its different. so any suggestion? Many thanks!!!

Comment: Please compare your configuration file with the standalone-preview.xml in the configuration directory of your JBoss. Have you added the extension element for the messaging subsystem?

Comment: @JaySmith I couldn't find standalone-preview.xml file, and Yes I added a extension element for messaging system, since it wasn't working I reverted the standalone file to the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check line number 3

> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]

You have added something in xml which is not formatted/unacceptable.